# Right to left support for iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any simple way to support the right to left languages in iOS? First way I can think of is redesigning the views/xibs, but that takes too much time for the whole app. Is there an easier way?

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203442/ios-how-to-restart-app-for-changing-language-swift-4/52203769#52203769

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing to right to left RTL programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151038/changing-to-right-to-left-rtl-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

try

In `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

    return true
}
```

Let us know .. is working ?

Comment: Hey, it did work partially. 50% of the views did get changed. Thanks!